# Automate JUnit tests for functionality on the server in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, web-applications, jetty, junit4

I would have added some JUnit tests to an Eclipse project that test functionality on the server to an Eclipse web project.

I can run the web application from inside Eclipse on an external Tomcat server (`Run As` | `Run on Server`) and then run the JUnit tests also from inside Eclipse while the first is still up.

I understand that is should be possible to fully automate both steps as one by making use of a Jetty (instead of Tomcat) server that runs inside Eclipse and that could be booted e.g. in `@BeforeClass` (or earlier).

Does Eclipse support this kind of unit testing out-of-the-box. I am currently using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Version: Kepler Service Release 2).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse (and any other IDE for that matter) doesn't stop you from doing anything in unit tests. It doesn't really support much, either, which is the core of your problem: Eclipse won't start a server for your unit tests. The same is true for all other IDEs that I know of.

Instead, you need to read up on how to [embed Jetty in a Java application](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) (= your unit tests) so the first test can start the server. Use a lazy init pattern for this:

```
private static JettyManager jetty;

@Before public void startServer() {
    if( null == jetty ) {
        jetty = new JettyManager();
        jetty.start();
    }
}
```

You can use a JVM shutdown hook to cleanly stop the server.

I use the same pattern to create the database which should be used during the tests to make sure it's clean. For this, I [embed an H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html).

If you want more automation, look at Maven. It can run integration tests (including deploying the WAR before starting the tests). See http://www.benoitschweblin.com/2013/03/run-jetty-in-maven-life-cycle.html

With the [Maven Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin), you can deploy to almost every J2EE container.

Or use Jenkins: http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/building-a-deployment-pipeline-using-git-maven-jenkins-and-glassfish-part-2-of-2/

Comment: Too bad there is not more built-in support.

Comment: You may want to look at Maven which can run integration tests (including deploying the WAR before starting the tests). See http://www.benoitschweblin.com/2013/03/run-jetty-in-maven-life-cycle.html With the Maven Cargo plugin, you can deploy to almost every J2EE container: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin Or use Jenkins: http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/building-a-deployment-pipeline-using-git-maven-jenkins-and-glassfish-part-2-of-2/